# OPENCART 2.0 IMAGE MANAGER NOT WORKING

Tags: opencart

**IF NOT WORKING THEN CHANGE THE CODE  IN FOLLOWING  : 
Admin /conroller / common /  filemanager.php**

BY VINAY SINGH  [ vinaysingh43@gmail.com]
skype : vinaysingh43

or Chagne the Code in line no  GLOBAL_BRACE

CONSTANT this contstant not wroking wth some server  ...

```html
<?php

class ControllerCommonFileManager extends Controller {

public function index() {

$this->load->language('common/filemanager');



if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {

$filter_name = rtrim(str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..', '*'), '', $this->request->get['filter_name']), '/');

} else {

$filter_name = null;

}



// Make sure we have the correct directory

if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$directory = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/' . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $this->request->get['directory']), '/');

} else {

$directory = DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog';

}



if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {

$page = $this->request->get['page'];

} else {

$page = 1;

}



$data['images'] = array();



$this->load->model('tool/image');



// Get directories

$directories = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);



if (!$directories) {

$directories = array();

}



// Get files

// $files = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,JPG,JPEG,PNG,GIF}', GLOB_BRACE);



$files1 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.jpg');

if (!$files1) {

$files1 = array();

}



$files2 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.jpeg');

if (!$files2) {

$files2 = array();

}



$files3 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.JPG');

if (!$files3) {

$files3 = array();

}



$files4 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.png');

if (!$files4) {

$files4 = array();

}



$files5 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.JPEG');

if (!$files5) {

$files5 = array();

}



$files6 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.PNG');

if (!$files6) {

$files6 = array();

}



$files7 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.GIF');

if (!$files7) {

$files7 = array();

}

$files8 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.gif');

if (!$files8) {

$files8 = array();

}





$files = array_merge($files1, $files2,$files3,$files4,$files5,$files6,$files7,$files8);





// Merge directories and files

$images = array_merge($directories, $files);



// Get total number of files and directories

$image_total = count($images);



// Split the array based on current page number and max number of items per page of 10

$images = array_splice($images, ($page - 1) * 16, 16);



foreach ($images as $image) {

$name = str_split(basename($image), 14);



if (is_dir($image)) {

 $url = '';



 if (isset($this->request->get['target'])) {

     $url .= '&target=' . $this->request->get['target'];

 }



 if (isset($this->request->get['thumb'])) {

     $url .= '&thumb=' . $this->request->get['thumb'];

 }



 $data['images'][] = array(

     'thumb' => '',

     'name'  => implode(' ', $name),

     'type'  => 'directory',

     'path'  => utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(DIR_IMAGE)),

     'href'  => $this->url->link('common/filemanager', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&directory=' . urlencode(utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/'))) . $url, true)

 );

} elseif (is_file($image)) {

 // Find which protocol to use to pass the full image link back

 if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {

     $server = HTTPS_CATALOG;

 } else {

     $server = HTTP_CATALOG;

 }



 $data['images'][] = array(

     'thumb' => $this->model_tool_image->resize(utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(DIR_IMAGE)), 100, 100),

     'name'  => implode(' ', $name),

     'type'  => 'image',

     'path'  => utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(DIR_IMAGE)),

     'href'  => $server . 'image/' . utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(DIR_IMAGE))

 );

}

}



$data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');



$data['text_no_results'] = $this->language->get('text_no_results');

$data['text_confirm'] = $this->language->get('text_confirm');



$data['entry_search'] = $this->language->get('entry_search');

$data['entry_folder'] = $this->language->get('entry_folder');



$data['button_parent'] = $this->language->get('button_parent');

$data['button_refresh'] = $this->language->get('button_refresh');

$data['button_upload'] = $this->language->get('button_upload');

$data['button_folder'] = $this->language->get('button_folder');

$data['button_delete'] = $this->language->get('button_delete');

$data['button_search'] = $this->language->get('button_search');



$data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];



if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$data['directory'] = urlencode($this->request->get['directory']);

} else {

$data['directory'] = '';

}



if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {

$data['filter_name'] = $this->request->get['filter_name'];

} else {

$data['filter_name'] = '';

}



// Return the target ID for the file manager to set the value

if (isset($this->request->get['target'])) {

$data['target'] = $this->request->get['target'];

} else {

$data['target'] = '';

}



// Return the thumbnail for the file manager to show a thumbnail

if (isset($this->request->get['thumb'])) {

$data['thumb'] = $this->request->get['thumb'];

} else {

$data['thumb'] = '';

}



// Parent

$url = '';



if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$pos = strrpos($this->request->get['directory'], '/');



if ($pos) {

 $url .= '&directory=' . urlencode(substr($this->request->get['directory'], 0, $pos));

}

}



if (isset($this->request->get['target'])) {

$url .= '&target=' . $this->request->get['target'];

}



if (isset($this->request->get['thumb'])) {

$url .= '&thumb=' . $this->request->get['thumb'];

}



$data['parent'] = $this->url->link('common/filemanager', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, true);



// Refresh

$url = '';



if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$url .= '&directory=' . urlencode($this->request->get['directory']);

}



if (isset($this->request->get['target'])) {

$url .= '&target=' . $this->request->get['target'];

}



if (isset($this->request->get['thumb'])) {

$url .= '&thumb=' . $this->request->get['thumb'];

}



$data['refresh'] = $this->url->link('common/filemanager', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, true);



$url = '';



if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$url .= '&directory=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['directory'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

}



if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {

$url .= '&filter_name=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['filter_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

}



if (isset($this->request->get['target'])) {

$url .= '&target=' . $this->request->get['target'];

}



if (isset($this->request->get['thumb'])) {

$url .= '&thumb=' . $this->request->get['thumb'];

}



$pagination = new Pagination();

$pagination->total = $image_total;

$pagination->page = $page;

$pagination->limit = 16;

$pagination->url = $this->url->link('common/filemanager', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url . '&page={page}', true);



$data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();



$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('common/filemanager', $data));

}



public function upload() {

$this->load->language('common/filemanager');



$json = array();



// Check user has permission

if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'common/filemanager')) {

$json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');

}



// Make sure we have the correct directory

if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$directory = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/' . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $this->request->get['directory']), '/');

} else {

$directory = DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog';

}



// Check its a directory

if (!is_dir($directory)) {

$json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_directory');

}



if (!$json) {

if (!empty($this->request->files['file']['name']) && is_file($this->request->files['file']['tmp_name'])) {

 // Sanitize the filename

 $filename = basename(html_entity_decode($this->request->files['file']['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));



 // Validate the filename length

 if ((utf8_strlen($filename) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($filename) > 255)) {

     $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_filename');

 }



 // Allowed file extension types

 $allowed = array(

     'jpg',

     'jpeg',

     'gif',

     'png'

 );



 if (!in_array(utf8_strtolower(utf8_substr(strrchr($filename, '.'), 1)), $allowed)) {

     $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_filetype');

 }



 // Allowed file mime types

 $allowed = array(

     'image/jpeg',

     'image/pjpeg',

     'image/png',

     'image/x-png',

     'image/gif'

 );



 if (!in_array($this->request->files['file']['type'], $allowed)) {

     $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_filetype');

 }



 // Return any upload error

 if ($this->request->files['file']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

     $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_upload_' . $this->request->files['file']['error']);

 }

} else {

 $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_upload');

}

}



if (!$json) {

move_uploaded_file($this->request->files['file']['tmp_name'], $directory . '/' . $filename);



$json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_uploaded');

}



$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');

$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));

}



public function folder() {

$this->load->language('common/filemanager');



$json = array();



// Check user has permission

if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'common/filemanager')) {

$json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');

}



// Make sure we have the correct directory

if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {

$directory = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/' . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $this->request->get['directory']), '/');

} else {

$directory = DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog';

}



// Check its a directory

if (!is_dir($directory)) {

$json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_directory');

}



if (!$json) {

// Sanitize the folder name

$folder = str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', basename(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['folder'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));



// Validate the filename length

if ((utf8_strlen($folder) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($folder) > 128)) {

 $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_folder');

}



// Check if directory already exists or not

if (is_dir($directory . '/' . $folder)) {

 $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_exists');

}

}



if (!$json) {

mkdir($directory . '/' . $folder, 0777);

chmod($directory . '/' . $folder, 0777);



$json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_directory');

}



$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');

$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));

}



public function delete() {

$this->load->language('common/filemanager');



$json = array();



// Check user has permission

if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'common/filemanager')) {

$json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');

}



if (isset($this->request->post['path'])) {

$paths = $this->request->post['path'];

} else {

$paths = array();

}



// Loop through each path to run validations

foreach ($paths as $path) {

$path = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $path), '/');



// Check path exsists

if ($path == DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog') {

 $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_delete');



 break;

}

}



if (!$json) {

// Loop through each path

foreach ($paths as $path) {

 $path = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $path), '/');



 // If path is just a file delete it

 if (is_file($path)) {

     unlink($path);



 // If path is a directory beging deleting each file and sub folder

 } elseif (is_dir($path)) {

     $files = array();



     // Make path into an array

     $path = array($path . '*');



     // While the path array is still populated keep looping through

     while (count($path) != 0) {

         $next = array_shift($path);



         foreach (glob($next) as $file) {

             // If directory add to path array

             if (is_dir($file)) {

                 $path[] = $file . '/*';

             }



             // Add the file to the files to be deleted array

             $files[] = $file;

         }

     }

     // Reverse sort the file array
        rsort($files);

        foreach ($files as $file) {

         // If file just delete

         if (is_file($file)) {

             unlink($file);



         // If directory use the remove directory function

         } elseif (is_dir($file)) {

        rmdir($file);

         }

     }
 }

}
$json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_delete');

}
$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');

$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer partially helped me. I could see all the files, but not upload them anymore. I got an error regarding an unknown path.

This worked for me though. (same file you've posted)

```html
<?php
class ControllerCommonFileManager extends Controller {
 public function index() {
  $this->load->language('common/filemanager');

  // Find which protocol to use to pass the full image link back
  if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
   $server = HTTPS_CATALOG;
  } else {
   $server = HTTP_CATALOG;
  }

  if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {
   $filter_name = rtrim(str_replace('*', '', $this->request->get['filter_name']), '/');
  } else {
   $filter_name = null;
  }

  // Make sure we have the correct directory
  if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {
   $directory = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/' . str_replace('*', '', $this->request->get['directory']), '/');
  } else {
   $directory = DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog';
  }

  if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
   $page = $this->request->get['page'];
  } else {
   $page = 1;
  }

  $directories = array();
  $files = array();

  $data['images'] = array();

  $this->load->model('tool/image');

  if (substr(str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($directory . '/' . $filter_name)), 0, strlen(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog')) == DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog') {
   // Get directories
   $directories = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

   if (!$directories) {
    $directories = array();
   }

   // Get files
   $files1 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.jpg');

if (!$files1) {

$files1 = array();

}



$files2 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.jpeg');

if (!$files2) {

$files2 = array();

}



$files3 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.JPG');

if (!$files3) {

$files3 = array();

}



$files4 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.png');

if (!$files4) {

$files4 = array();

}



$files5 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.JPEG');

if (!$files5) {

$files5 = array();

}



$files6 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.PNG');

if (!$files6) {

$files6 = array();

}



$files7 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.GIF');

if (!$files7) {

$files7 = array();

}

$files8 = glob($directory . '/' . $filter_name . '*.gif');

if (!$files8) {

$files8 = array();

}





$files = array_merge($files1, $files2,$files3,$files4,$files5,$files6,$files7,$files8);



  }

  // Merge directories and files
  $images = array_merge($directories, $files);

  // Get total number of files and directories
  $image_total = count($images);

  // Split the array based on current page number and max number of items per page of 10
  $images = array_splice($images, ($page - 1) * 16, 16);

  foreach ($images as $image) {
   $name = str_split(basename($image), 14);

   if (is_dir($image)) {
    $url = '';

    if (isset($this->request->get['target'])) {
     $url .= '&target=' . $this->request->get['target'];
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['thumb'])) {
     $url .= '&thumb=' . $this->request->get['thumb'];
    }

    $data['images'][] = array(
     'thumb' => '',
     'name'  => implode(' ', $name),
     'type'  => 'directory',
     'path'  => utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(DIR_IMAGE)),
     'href'  => $this->url->link('common/filemanager', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&directory=' . urlencode(utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/'))) . $url, true)
    );
   } elseif (is_file($image)) {
    $data['images'][] = array(
     'thumb' => $this->model_tool_image->resize(utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(DIR_IMAGE)), 100, 100),
     'name'  => implode(' ', $name),
     'type'  => 'image',
     'path'  => utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(DIR_IMAGE)),
     'href'  => $server . 'image/' . utf8_substr($image, utf8_strlen(DIR_IMAGE))
    );
   }
  }

  $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

  $data['text_no_results'] = $this->language->get('text_no_results');
  $data['text_confirm'] = $this->language->get('text_confirm');

  $data['entry_search'] = $this->language->get('entry_search');
  $data['entry_folder'] = $this->language->get('entry_folder');

  $data['button_parent'] = $this->language->get('button_parent');
  $data['button_refresh'] = $this->language->get('button_refresh');
  $data['button_upload'] = $this->language->get('button_upload');
  $data['button_folder'] = $this->language->get('button_folder');
  $data['button_delete'] = $this->language->get('button_delete');
  $data['button_search'] = $this->language->get('button_search');

  $data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];

  if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {
   $data['directory'] = urlencode($this->request->get['directory']);
  } else {
   $data['directory'] = '';
  }

  if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {
   $data['filter_name'] = $this->request->get['filter_name'];
  } else {
   $data['filter_name'] = '';
  }

  // Return the target ID for the file manager to set the value
  if (isset($this->request->get['target'])) {
   $data['target'] = $this->request->get['target'];
  } else {
   $data['target'] = '';
  }

  // Return the thumbnail for the file manager to show a thumbnail
  if (isset($this->request->get['thumb'])) {
   $data['thumb'] = $this->request->get['thumb'];
  } else {
   $data['thumb'] = '';
  }

  // Parent
  $url = '';

  if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {
   $pos = strrpos($this->request->get['directory'], '/');

   if ($pos) {
    $url .= '&directory=' . urlencode(substr($this->request->get['directory'], 0, $pos));
   }
  }

  if (isset($this->request->get['target'])) {
   $url .= '&target=' . $this->request->get['target'];
  }

  if (isset($this->request->get['thumb'])) {
   $url .= '&thumb=' . $this->request->get['thumb'];
  }

  $data['parent'] = $this->url->link('common/filemanager', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, true);

  // Refresh
  $url = '';

  if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {
   $url .= '&directory=' . urlencode($this->request->get['directory']);
  }

  if (isset($this->request->get['target'])) {
   $url .= '&target=' . $this->request->get['target'];
  }

  if (isset($this->request->get['thumb'])) {
   $url .= '&thumb=' . $this->request->get['thumb'];
  }

  $data['refresh'] = $this->url->link('common/filemanager', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, true);

  $url = '';

  if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {
   $url .= '&directory=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['directory'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  }

  if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {
   $url .= '&filter_name=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['filter_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
  }

  if (isset($this->request->get['target'])) {
   $url .= '&target=' . $this->request->get['target'];
  }

  if (isset($this->request->get['thumb'])) {
   $url .= '&thumb=' . $this->request->get['thumb'];
  }

  $pagination = new Pagination();
  $pagination->total = $image_total;
  $pagination->page = $page;
  $pagination->limit = 16;
  $pagination->url = $this->url->link('common/filemanager', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url . '&page={page}', true);

  $data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();

  $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('common/filemanager', $data));
 }

 public function upload() {
  $this->load->language('common/filemanager');

  $json = array();

  // Check user has permission
  if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'common/filemanager')) {
   $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
  }

  // Make sure we have the correct directory
  if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {
   $directory = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/' . $this->request->get['directory'], '/');
  } else {
   $directory = DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog';
  }

  // Check its a directory
  if (!is_dir($directory) || substr(str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($directory)), 0, strlen(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog')) != DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog') {
   $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_directory');
  }

  if (!$json) {
   // Check if multiple files are uploaded or just one
   $files = array();

   if (!empty($this->request->files['file']['name']) && is_array($this->request->files['file']['name'])) {
    foreach (array_keys($this->request->files['file']['name']) as $key) {
     $files[] = array(
      'name'     => $this->request->files['file']['name'][$key],
      'type'     => $this->request->files['file']['type'][$key],
      'tmp_name' => $this->request->files['file']['tmp_name'][$key],
      'error'    => $this->request->files['file']['error'][$key],
      'size'     => $this->request->files['file']['size'][$key]
     );
    }
   }

   foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (is_file($file['tmp_name'])) {
     // Sanitize the filename
     $filename = basename(html_entity_decode($file['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

     // Validate the filename length
     if ((utf8_strlen($filename) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($filename) > 255)) {
      $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_filename');
     }
     
     // Allowed file extension types
     $allowed = array(
      'jpg',
      'jpeg',
      'gif',
      'png'
     );
 
     if (!in_array(utf8_strtolower(utf8_substr(strrchr($filename, '.'), 1)), $allowed)) {
      $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_filetype');
     }
     
     // Allowed file mime types
     $allowed = array(
      'image/jpeg',
      'image/pjpeg',
      'image/png',
      'image/x-png',
      'image/gif'
     );
 
     if (!in_array($file['type'], $allowed)) {
      $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_filetype');
     }

     // Return any upload error
     if ($file['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
      $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_upload_' . $file['error']);
     }
    } else {
     $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_upload');
    }

    if (!$json) {
     move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $directory . '/' . $filename);
    }
   }
  }

  if (!$json) {
   $json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_uploaded');
  }

  $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
  $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
 }

 public function folder() {
  $this->load->language('common/filemanager');

  $json = array();

  // Check user has permission
  if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'common/filemanager')) {
   $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
  }

  // Make sure we have the correct directory
  if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {
   $directory = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/' . $this->request->get['directory'], '/');
  } else {
   $directory = DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog';
  }

  // Check its a directory
  if (!is_dir($directory) || substr(str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($directory)), 0, strlen(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog')) != DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog') {
   $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_directory');
  }

  if ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   // Sanitize the folder name
   $folder = basename(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['folder'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

   // Validate the filename length
   if ((utf8_strlen($folder) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($folder) > 128)) {
    $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_folder');
   }

   // Check if directory already exists or not
   if (is_dir($directory . '/' . $folder)) {
    $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_exists');
   }
  }

  if (!isset($json['error'])) {
   mkdir($directory . '/' . $folder, 0777);
   chmod($directory . '/' . $folder, 0777);

   @touch($directory . '/' . $folder . '/' . 'index.html');

   $json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_directory');
  }

  $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
  $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
 }

 public function delete() {
  $this->load->language('common/filemanager');

  $json = array();

  // Check user has permission
  if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'common/filemanager')) {
   $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
  }

  if (isset($this->request->post['path'])) {
   $paths = $this->request->post['path'];
  } else {
   $paths = array();
  }

  // Loop through each path to run validations
  foreach ($paths as $path) {
   // Check path exsists
   if ($path == DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog' || substr(str_replace('\\', '/', realpath(DIR_IMAGE . $path)), 0, strlen(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog')) != DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog') {
    $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_delete');

    break;
   }
  }

  if (!$json) {
   // Loop through each path
   foreach ($paths as $path) {
    $path = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . $path, '/');

    // If path is just a file delete it
    if (is_file($path)) {
     unlink($path);

    // If path is a directory beging deleting each file and sub folder
    } elseif (is_dir($path)) {
     $files = array();

     // Make path into an array
     $path = array($path . '*');

     // While the path array is still populated keep looping through
     while (count($path) != 0) {
      $next = array_shift($path);

      foreach (glob($next) as $file) {
       // If directory add to path array
       if (is_dir($file)) {
        $path[] = $file . '/*';
       }

       // Add the file to the files to be deleted array
       $files[] = $file;
      }
     }

     // Reverse sort the file array
     rsort($files);

     foreach ($files as $file) {
      // If file just delete
      if (is_file($file)) {
       unlink($file);

      // If directory use the remove directory function
      } elseif (is_dir($file)) {
       rmdir($file);
      }
     }
    }
   }

   $json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_delete');
  }

  $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
  $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
 }
}
```